# What is the best way to wrap unmanaged C++ classes so they can be consumed by .Net managed client applications?

Tags: c++, .net, pinvoke, marshalling

We have a win32 C++ unmanaged library (which calls Boost and openCV under the covers).
The library contains several public class definitions.
The classes themselves expose several methods who's parameters include vectors, shared pointers
and callbacks as part of their method signatures.

We would like to create a wrapper which would allow these classes to be consumed by .Net (managed) clients.
We want to preserve support for our existing unmanaged client applications. So I guess this will have to be
a separate DLL/library. Another consideration is performance marshaling across the managed/unmanaged 
boundary. We'll be pushing byte arrays of images back and forth between the client app and libraries at 
the rate of 30-50 times per second.

What is the best approach for doing this?

Can someone point me in the direction of any sample implementations, tutorials, strategies to get us started?
The last time I looked at something like this was well over 10 years ago.
I seem to vaguely remember pInvoke and the IJW works.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: If this is a high-performance application then I'd avoid doing data-transfer to/from .NET so frequently. Try to find a way that minimizes the amount of ,NET code that is executed, especially in a tight-loop. I would suggest exporting functionality via COM interfaces rather than Managed C++ or any kind of interop of that nature.

Comment: @Dai:  Thx for quick response. The bulk of the heavy lifting computations is completed in the unmanaged layer. The managed layer captures data/images, pushes it to unmanaged libraries for processing and then consumes the results. Can you expand on the COM interface idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a managed C++ wrapped around your native C++.
Compile your native C++ into a static library, create managed C++ DLL that references your static C++ library and write the wrapper code. I have done it a few times and it is pretty straightforward.

Check out this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes#A8

Comment: No need for a static library. Compile the code right in. Also, it's C++/CLI and not managed C++ these days.